# Can a promise callback be ever delayed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

When we design a function that returns a promise, like this:

```
function getAsyncResult() {

    // synchronous code 1

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        // synchronous code 2

        // asynchronous code

    });
}
```

Does it make a difference whether we place our synchronous code before we create the resulting promise or at the beginning of the callback?

In other words, is it possible that there can be a delay between `new Promise(...)` and the call into its callback function?

To rephrase it again, is it possible that `synchronous code 2` ever executes with a delay, and not immediately after `synchronous code 1`?

P.S. I am mostly interested in this with respect to ES6 Promise and Bluebird, although would be nice to know if other major libraries do it differently.

Comment: __unclear what you're asking__... Do share an example to express what you are asking...

Comment: I have added another clarification.

Comment: `Delay` ? Do you mean once promise is fulfilled ?

Comment: @Rayon, no, my example wouldn't even get there at that point. I'm asking about the part before it even gets into the asynchronous part.

Comment: Try to rephrase it with some alerts or `console`... Unclear :( Statements are being interpreted serially.. What is not working for you...

Comment: i dont think so. if your function is returning a promise then just move your synchronous code inside the promise and use thens to control the execution

Comment: @vbranden I'd like to be certain on this one, as it affects the function design.

Comment: if you want to use delays use a promise library like bluebird. http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.delay.html

Comment: @vbranden I don't want to use delays. That is not my question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise 
"the executor is called before the Promise constructor even returns the created object"

Comment: @pvg That's close to an answer. I wonder now, if libraries like Bluebird follow that also.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's actually the answer but you're better off, for the sake of clarity, factor your code so there is no critical dependency on this behaviour.

Comment: @pvg then there would be no point asking this question to begin with :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [ES6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-constructor), what it calls the "executor" (the callback passed to the constructor) is executed immediately. Therefore, an implementation which did not behave this way would not be conforming, and you can depend on it.

Therefore, you can put your code either before calling the constructor, or within the executor, and it should not make any difference in terms of execution timing (although as another answer pointed out, there will be differences in terms of what happens if the code throws).

Other implementations may vary, and some may not even provide the ES6-style promise constructor, choosing to build promises in some other way.

Comment: Do you know if the major libraries, like Bluebird, When, Q are compliant in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

With ES6/compliant Promise, `synchronous code 1` and `synchronous code 2` will (barring an uncaught error) execute in that order, in the same event turn. However, there is a difference :

- **synchronous code 1**: An uncaught error will throw (to the console) in the usual way.
- **synchronous code 2**: An uncaught error will give rise to Promise rejection.

`asynchronous code` doesn't really exist, at least not at this level; only inner functions can execute later. You may call a function that returns a promise. Such a promise, `p`, may be used to resolve/reject the outer Promise (the one being constructed), without using `.then()`, using the syntax `resolve(p)`, in the same way you would write `resolve(value)`.

With a `resolve(p)` statement in place, if `p` was to reject, then the outer Promise would also reject even though its own revealed `reject` method is not called explicitly by user code.

Comment: Right, exception handling is the main difference here. To rephrase it: In case of an error **sync code 1** is going to throw a normal synchronous exception which terminates the function immediately, while **sync code 2** is going to trigger a rejection, which can be caught asynchronously by subsequent catch handlers inside the `Promise` chain.

Comment: @Iven, yes, well put.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise` is invented to avert the phenomenon known as callback hell. It is nothing but a structured system where you can register your callbacks more neatly than creating a nexus of it right in the middle of your code. Except this there is no asynchronous magic happening in `Promise`.

Lets look at this

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        // synchronous code 2

        // asynchronous code

    });
```

You are returning a promise which provide the facility to hook two functions (resolve and reject) which will be called (by you) after an asynchronous operation **which will also be initiated by you** inside the promise function.

This can be an input from the user, an ajax request etc - which you really don't know when is going to happen.

The execution of code inside your promise constructor happens immediately where you can start your asynchronous process (`synchronous code 2`) before reaching any other line of code.

If you really need to separate the linear execution of `synchronous code 2` and `asynchronous code`, probably you can put the latter inside a `setTimeout` function. This way it is executed when the browser gets the next breathing space. But that kind of practice is little skewed in the face of the concept of `Promise`.

Comment: `The execution of code inside your promise constructor happens immediately...` - this paragraph would suffice, the rest - I wasn't asking about. Would be nice to know if all major promise libraries follow this pattern.

Comment: The answer is not only for you. It is meant to help all the others who happens to land on this question.

Comment: Well done then! :) I will wait for others have a say before accepting the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no delay will happen: the code will be executed in the same stack, synchronously.

As a proof, you can run this snippet:

```
console.log('sync code before promise');

new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  console.log('sync code in promise');
});

console.log('sync code after promise');
```

Result is before -> in -> after